# Optimization for query n increase performance

Tags: optimization

I am executing the following query:

```
select count(inspection_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and inspection_result= 1 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(inspection_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and inspection_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_1_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_1_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_2_value_1_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_2_value_1_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_2_value_2_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_2_value_2_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_3_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_3_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_4_value_1_result) table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_4_value_1_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_4_value_2_result) from table where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_4_value_2_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1" 
union all 
select count(defect_5_result) from tabele where (inspection_time between "2015-06-28" and "2015-07-04") and defect_5_result= 0 and part_type = "39000048" and location = "1"
```

I have done partitions according to the start of month, that is, there are 12 partitions and the columns which are present in the column are indexed.

I have presently 1 million rows of data, each row is 128 bytes.
I need to optimize the query and increase the performance. Can anyone help?

Comment: This does not look valid SQL to me (because of the double quotes).  Which RDBMS is this?  And how would you expect anybody to help improving the performance without telling how your present query performs?  So, please include the real query, table and index definitions, and an execution plan that shows that this is inefficient.

Comment: In the first two lines of your union, can you not eliminate them by getting rid of the `inspection_result` part - either 1 or 0. If there are no other values (and from the name, there shouldn't be) - so why that UNION ALL for those first two lines? That's 1 problem that I can see. Do you have 1 million rows partitioned into 12? 1M rows isn't a reason to start partitioning.

Comment: It is mysql query..